# Ansible Inventory Host Dependency

Tags: dependencies, ansible, inventory

I have a an ansible inventory for a bunch of oracle database servers. And most of the time I want my playbook to do it's thing in parallel. But for a specific set of RAC servers, I want to make sure ansible processes them serially. So my inventory looks like below. Please note this is just a sample and that there is actually 170+ hosts that are a mixture of standalone and RAC, so ideally the solution would be scalable:

```
[d1w1]
server1
server2

[d1w2]
hostA
hostB

[d1w3]
standalone1
standalone2
rac1
rac2
rac3
```

In this case, when I run ansible-playbook for "d1w3", the playbook will start executing for all 5 hosts simultaneously. I need it to do standalone1, standalone2, and rac1 simultaneously. And when rac1 completes successfully move on to rac2 and when rac2 is successful move on to rac3.

I'm aware of groups and children but I'm not sure how to make dependencies.

Any thoughts?

Comment: are the playbooks tasks the same ?

Comment: Yes the playbook tasks are the same if it is standalone or if it is rac.

Comment: The problem exposed is less clear, because actually you don't explain how your groups of servers are done in the inventory, which is a key information in ansible, it lacks also an understable workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I advice to look into making several plays in the same playbook. Each play will be run after the previous one on the defined `hosts`.

```
- name: parallel play on 3 hosts
  hosts: standalone1,standalone2,rac1
  tasks:
    - name: tasks 1
      …

- name: play on rac2 
  hosts: rac2
  tasks:
    - name: tasks 1
      …

- name: play on rac3 
  hosts: rac3
  tasks:
    - name: tasks 1
      …
```

Comment: This seems to require putting the hosts in the playbook. I actually have 170 hosts with a mixture of standalone and rac. I don't know that this would scale very well. Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

You may have to restructure, but you can still let the hosts file define.

```
[parallels]
1.2.3.4
1.2.3.5

[serials]
2.3.4.5
2.3.4.6
2.3.4.7
```

Then you can break into just a couple plays -

```
- name: Do The Thing
  hosts: parallels
  roles:
   - test

- name: Do The Thing in serial
  hosts: serials
  serial: 1
  roles:
   - test
```

That still probably isn't quite what you want, but if you combine it with [baptistemm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338011/baptistemm)'s solution, it might work. How deep does the dependency go?

If you put all the ones that have to be done first in one group, then all the ones that depend on those in a second group, then all the ones that depend on the *2nd* group into a third, you can parallel all the wave 1's, then the wave 2's, then the wave 3's, etc.

You'll likely have to use `--limit` statements, but it could work.